# Azure Retrieve file icon doesnt work published, SHGetFileInfo

Tags: azure

When not published, but using azure storage live, extract file icon works.

When I publish my project, (still using the same storage, azure website free/shared), I cant extract the file icon, (500 internal server error).

**UPLOAD ICON**

```
Icon fileIcon = FileIconLoader.GetFileIcon(fileextension); 

CloudBlobContainer blobIconContainer = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudBlobIconContainer();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobIconContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);  

Bitmap pngIcon = fileIcon.ToBitmap();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
pngIcon.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
```

**//RETRIEVE ICON FUNCTION**

```
public static class FileIconLoader
    {
        private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
        private const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
        private const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;
        private const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x10;

        private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80;

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath,
        uint dwFileAttributes,
        ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
        uint cbSizeFileInfo,
        uint uFlags);

        public static Icon GetFileIcon(string fileExtension)
        {
            fileExtension = "*" + fileExtension; //om inte fil finns 

            SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
            IntPtr hImg;
            hImg = SHGetFileInfo(fileExtension, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, ref shinfo,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
            SHGFI_ICON |
            SHGFI_LARGEICON |
            SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);

            try
            {
                return Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Errormessage in browser console window:**

POST mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Folder/Upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

How come it doesn't work published?

Really reeeaally appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure but the error could be related to lack of permissions when executing certain code in Azure Websites as Azure Websites run in a pretty locked down mode (you can't manipulate registry for example) as many websites run in a single VM.

Comment: So basically I'm screwed;D?

Comment: Cloud Services or Virtual Machines are your new best friends :)

Comment: Really want it to be a website.. Are there no other ways?

Comment: There's another thing (unrelated to this problem) that you might want to think about - If I am not mistaken, icons are returned based on the applications installed on the machine. For example, if Acrobat reader is not installed on the machine, I don't think you will get an icon you are expecting. How would you deal with that situation. One solution would be to create the icons on your machine, store them as PNGs and use them in your application. Will this solution work for you?

Comment: Yes that would work but how can I create all these pngs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is something we wrote some time back just for this purpose. What it does is find all the registered file types from the registry (`GetFileType` method) and then extracts the icons for all of them and saves it in PNG format (`GetIconImageFromFilename`). Hope this helps.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegistryFileExtensionWithIcon
{
    public class RegistryFileName
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Bitmap> FileIconAssociation = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();

        public static List<string> GetFileType()
        {

            List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                // Create a registry key object to represent the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry section
                RegistryKey rkRoot = Registry.ClassesRoot;

                //Gets all sub keys' names.
                string[] keyNames = rkRoot.GetSubKeyNames();
                //Hashtable iconsInfo = new Hashtable();

                //Find the file icon.
                foreach (string keyName in keyNames)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName))
                        continue;
                    int indexOfPoint = keyName.IndexOf(".");

                    //If this key is not a file exttension(eg, .zip), skip it.
                    if (indexOfPoint != 0)
                        continue;

                    RegistryKey rkFileType = rkRoot.OpenSubKey(keyName);
                    if (rkFileType == null)
                        continue;
                    allFiles.Add(keyName);
                    rkFileType.Close();
                }
                rkRoot.Close();
                return allFiles;
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }

        public static void GetIconImageFromFilename(List<string> FileNames)
        {
            Bitmap bmpImage = null;
            string FileExtension = string.Empty;
            foreach (var file in FileNames)
            {
                int IndexOfLastDot = file.LastIndexOf(".");
                if (IndexOfLastDot >= 0)
                {
                    FileExtension = file.Substring(IndexOfLastDot + 1).ToLower();
                }
                if (!FileIconAssociation.TryGetValue(FileExtension, out bmpImage))
                {
                    IntPtr sImgSmall;    
                    SHFILEINFO shinfoForSmallIcon = new SHFILEINFO();
                    sImgSmall = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(file, 0, ref shinfoForSmallIcon, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfoForSmallIcon),Win32.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | Win32.SHGFI_ICON | Win32.SHGFI_SMALLICON );
                    System.Drawing.Icon smallIcon = (System.Drawing.Icon)(System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfoForSmallIcon.hIcon).Clone());
                    Win32.DestroyIcon(shinfoForSmallIcon.hIcon);
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp1 = smallIcon.ToBitmap();
                    string location = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath) + "\\DownloadIcons\\16x16\\";
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(location);
                    string completeFilePath1 = string.Format("{0}{1}.png", location, FileExtension);
                    bmp1.Save(completeFilePath1, ImageFormat.Png);



                    IntPtr hImgLarge;   

                    SHFILEINFO shinfoForLargeIcon = new SHFILEINFO();
                    hImgLarge = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(file, 0, ref shinfoForLargeIcon, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfoForLargeIcon),
                        Win32.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | Win32.SHGFI_ICON | Win32.SHGFI_LARGEICON );
                    System.Drawing.Icon largeIcon = (System.Drawing.Icon)(System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfoForLargeIcon.hIcon).Clone());
                    Win32.DestroyIcon(shinfoForLargeIcon.hIcon);
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp2 = largeIcon.ToBitmap();
                    string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath) + "\\DownloadIcons\\32x32\\";
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);

                    string completeFilePath2 = string.Format("{0}{1}.png", filePath, FileExtension);
                    bmp2.Save(completeFilePath2, ImageFormat.Png);

                }
            }
        }

        public struct SHFILEINFO
        {
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr iIcon;
            public uint dwAttributes;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string szDisplayName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
            public string szTypeName;
        };
    }

    public class Win32
    {
        public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;
        public const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200;
        public const uint SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400;
        public const uint SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800;
        public const uint SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000;
        public const uint SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000;
        public const uint SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000;
        public const uint SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000000000;// 0x000008000;
        public const uint SHGFI_SELECTED = 0x000010000;
        public const uint SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED = 0x000020000;
        public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;
        public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;
        public const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002;
        public const uint SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004;
        public const uint SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008;
        public const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010;
        public const uint SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS = 0x000000020;
        public const uint SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX = 0x000000040;
        //  public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
        //  public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;    // 'Large icon
        //  public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;    // 'Small icon
        public const uint ILD_TRANSPARENT = 0x1;

        public const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);

        public const UInt32 SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
        public const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        public const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        public const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);

            return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath,
         uint dwFileAttributes,
         ref RegistryFileName.SHFILEINFO psfi,
         uint cbSizeFileInfo,
         uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost too good to be true, Omg thank you that is very kind of you!

I found around 950 icons, are these all different names? Will there be complications if i put all of them in the same container? Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you out. Regarding different names, I would say yes as each icon is for a different registered file type on your computer. As far as putting these icons in one container, there should not be any complications. One thing I did notice was that the quality of the icon was not so great. But if you could live with that, all should be fine.

Comment: I'm OK with that:) One laaaast question, (I promise)! If i want the file extension for each file in that list..? Foreach file gives me names like 001, 002 etc(?), why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you please describe in more details. This is what I see in the `FileNames` list: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aalui.png.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. 001 was actually the file extension, thougt it was a listid or something. Nevermind, I'm all good now, thanks!

Comment: Encountered an error when trying to save all these icons.

Icon listnumber 157, fileextension: css

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

What caused this?